# curl from sitemap.xml?

Tags: curl, xargs

I would like to curl a list of URLs (Namely as defined in https://example.com/sitemap.xml

The closest I've been able to get to this goal is

```
xargs curl --referer https://mywebsite.ca --user-agent "It me yo" < listofurls.txt > /dev/null
```

Which works fine and dandy and hits the URLs I need to but seems unable to work with anything other than a local file. I also would like to make use of a list that exists already and keeps itself maintained (The sitemap.xml).

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation) to change `sitemap.xml` into into a list of URLs, one per line.  To do this on the command line you can use [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html), which is part of [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/).  So you'd do something like:

```
curl https://example.com/sitemap.xml | xsltproc stylesheet | xargs curl --blah --blah
```

Creating the XSLT stylesheet is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I'm after. Thank you. It looks like I already have xsltproc installed on my machine. I'll have to experiment/learn/play with the stylesheet aspect. It seems Yoast [has released stylesheets](https://yoast.com/xsl-stylesheet-xml-sitemap/) meant to work with their sitemaps already.